# Launchd plist running a bash script that calls a node process is exiting with status code 8

Tags: macos, node.js, bash, launchd

Here is my launchd playlist

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
          <string>com.blockjunk.server.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/Users/jeff/scripts/nojunkweb/startserver.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
          <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
          <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

And here is startserver.sh that it is calling

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Attempting to start node server"
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/jeff/scripts/nojunkweb/server.js "http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/" "https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/drills" "https://www.duolingo.com" "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

`launchctl list` shows error code 8 for com.blockjunk.server.plist - does anyone know status code 8 means or what I might be doing wrong?

Here's the permissions on startserver.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jeff  staff   248B Feb  6 10:16 startserver.sh

The plist is in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

Comment: same question on superuser: http://superuser.com/q/713312/4714

Comment: Yeah not sure where to post it because i'm not sure if its a launchd question or a node question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put the `plist` in `/Library/LaunchDeamons` to run it as `root` because the `node` process needed `root access`.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 8: Exec format error. A request was made to execute a file that, although it has the appropriate permissions, was not in the format required for an executable file.

Start the job manually from Terminal.app. What exactly is the error message?

**1) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 8**: launchd was unable to execute the job specified in `ProgramArguments`. Given that you specified a proper bang line this is unlikely.

**2) Exited with code: 8**: The script launchd called returned this error. Try running the script manually. Does it work?

It is important to know what *exactly* the error message is. Otherwise it is impossible to tell what error code 8 is because we do not know which process reported it. launchd reports standard error codes but software in general is not required to do that.

To find out what a standard error code means enter the following command:

```
perl -E 'say $!=shift' 8
```

Just replace the `8` by the code you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah the script runs fine manually when I run it from the command line. Were you able to find a list of error codes that includes 8?

Comment: Could it be a permissions thing? Here's the permissions on it -rwxr-xr-x  1 jeff  staff   248B Feb  6 10:16 startserver.sh

Comment: launchctl would tell you if the permissions were wrong (Error: Dubious permissions on file). First find out which process returned this code by looking at the logs.